# Waterfall plot with different x axis

Tags: matlab, plot, waterfall

I would like to make a waterfall plot in MATLAB using a different x axis for each plot. I want my plot to look like the picture in the answer to this question: [waterfall plot using ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393825/waterfall-plot-using-ribbon) , but in this exemple, 'xaxis' is the same for each curves . Is it possible to implement a similar procedure but with the ability to have different x axis ?

I know how to do a simple line plot with different axis using plot3 :

```
% plot (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) respectively at z1=1 and z2=2
plot3(x1, y1, repmat(1,size(x1)))
hold on ; plot3(x2, y2, repmat(2,size(x2)))
```

but I don't know if that can be adapted to a waterfall plot or, conversely, if using plot3 I can have a result that looks similar to the aforementioned example.

**edit:** Maybe it was not clear enough: what I would like to do is a weterfall plot, i.e. several (x,z) curves at different y values, but with different x vectors for each curves, like in this example generated with matplotlib (notice that the three curves don't share the same x range nor the same spacing between x values): 
[image: example_python]

As far as I know, the waterfall function of matlab is designed to use the same x vector for each curve, and I don't know how to bypass that (and the question currently marked as an answer does not address this issue).

Comment: is this good enough?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475533/looking-for-a-variation-of-waterfall-plot-in-matlab

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but from what I can tell in the both the question and the answers of this thread, it is assumed that all the (x,z) curves share the same x. What I would like to do is plotting something like (x1,z1), (x2,z2), ... not (x,z1), (x,z2), ...

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I am currently not employed in a company with a matlab license, so womeone else will have to help you. Happy hunting